# Different htaccess directory and subdirectory redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to have clean urls on my site and here is the mapping I'm trying to achieve:

1. mysite.tld/directory/ is going to > mysite.tld/page.php?q=directory
2. mysite.tld/tags/directory/ is going to > mysite.tld/tag.php?q=directory

I have made an htaccess file at the root of my site wiht the folling code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)\/?$ pages.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/d]+)/?$ tags.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

For some reason, the tag redirect works but is then "eaten" by the other rule of redirection. Not sure what to do to prevent second rule from doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is as follow:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/d]+)\/? /tags.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/tags
RewriteRule (.*) pages.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```